# Why do I get the error "TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found"?

Tags: python, unicode

After running this small program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
# -*-coding:utf-8 -*
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
title = u"""a=""" + a + u""", b=""" + str(b) + \
    u""", c=""" + str(c)
print(title)
```

I get the following error:

```
u""", c=""" + str(c)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found
```

But the following runs just fine!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
# -*-coding:utf-8 -*
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
title = u""", b=""" + str(b) + \
    u""", c=""" + str(c)
print(title)
```

Can somebody please explain me what is going on?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You didn't wrap `a` in a `str` call.  You need to do `str(a)` where you have `a`, just like you did for b and c.