# What does this error mean and can I fix it?

Tags: python, json, csv, twitter, tweepy

I am using the tweepy API to stream specific information and then store that into a CSV. It seems tweets are storing successfully but I keep getting the message `('failed ondata', 'coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found')` What does this message mean and how can I go about fixing it?

```
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
import time
import json, csv 
import sys 

import twitter_credentials




class listener(StreamListener):

  def on_data(self, data):
    try:

        tweet = json.loads(data) 
        text = tweet["text"]
        username = tweet["user"]["screen_name"]
        location = tweet["user"]["location"]
        created_at = tweet["created_at"]
        saveTweets = open('SaveTweets.csv', 'a')  #open a csv which we will append to 
        reload(sys)  
        sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
        saveTweets.write( "created_at : " + created_at +" Username : " + username + "Tweet Text : " + text + "Location : " + location)
        saveTweets.write('\n')

        saveTweets.close()
        return True

    except BaseException, e:
        print('failed ondata', str(e))
        time.sleep(5)







  def on_error(self, status):
      print(status)


auth = OAuthHandler(twitter_credentials.API_KEY, twitter_credentials.API_SECRET_KEY)
auth.set_access_token(twitter_credentials.ACCESS_TOKEN, twitter_credentials.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=["plumber"])
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/17182948/4908969

Comment: I added this method but am still getting the same message. Any other suggestions?

Comment: If you take out the `except` clause you might get a better view on where the error is actually occurring

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/10958477/9592801 and also you are trying to write `NoneType` I guess.

EDIT:
Lets assume your tweet json might look something like this and if you try to concatenate unicode with `None` you will encounter exactly same `TypeError`.

```
tweet = {
    "text": "some text",
    "user": {
        "screen_name": "screen 1",
        "location": "location 1"
    },
    "created_at": None
}

text = tweet["text"]
username = tweet["user"]["screen_name"]
location = tweet["user"]["location"]
created_at = tweet["created_at"]

data_to_write = u"created_at : " + created_at + u" Username : " + str(username) + u"Tweet Text : " + str(text) + u"Location : " + str(location)
```

output:

```
...
    data_to_write = u"created_at : " + created_at + u" Username : " + str(username) + u"Tweet Text : " + str(text) + u"Location : " + str(location)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found
```

Now if you wrap with `str()` you will come over this error as it will convert `None` to string.

```
data_to_write = u"created_at : " + str(created_at) + u" Username : " + str(username) + u"Tweet Text : " + str(text) + u"Location : " + str(location)
```

If this didnt solve your issue then please share some more details about your error(line number, python version etc) deep dive can be done. For example getting more info from exception.

```
import traceback;
import sys

print(sys.version)
try:
    ...
except BaseException as e:
    traceback.print_exc(err)
```

Comment: I don't t think that this post helps in my specific case. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Yamin, I have added my more context and explanation to my suggested link.